# extracting text from id in beautifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

have html code like this. using BeautifulSoup, i want to extract the text that is 2,441

have a span element and a id which is equals to lastPrice.

```
<span id="lastPrice">2,441.00</span>
```

I have tried to look up on the net and solve, but i am still unable to do it. I am a beginner.

```
i have tried this:
tag = soup.span
price = soup.find(id="lastPrice")
print(price.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The data you see on the page is rendered via JavaScript, so BeautifulSoup doesn't see the price. The price is embedded within the page in JavaScript form. You can extract it for example:

```py
import json
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www1.nseindia.com/live_market/dynaContent/live_watch/get_quote/GetQuote.jsp?symbol=HDFC"

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:97.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/97.0"
}

soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).content, "html.parser")
data = json.loads(soup.find(id="responseDiv").contents[0])

# uncomment this to print all data:
# print(json.dumps(data, indent=4))

print(data["data"][0]["lastPrice"])
```

Prints:

```
2,407.90
```

Comment: I'm facing a very similar issue on a different website. How do you know which tag contains the json data?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```js
price = soup.select("#lastPrice")[0] 
print(price.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not with bs4 but with regex is as follows:

```py
import re

line = '<span id="lastPrice">2,441.00</span>'
print(p.sub("", data))
```